Different notion of almost periodicity using almost periods
I was recently trying to make sense of the definition of Besicovitch almost periodicity. Motivated by the many equivalent definitions of Bohr almost periodicity, I was wondering whether the same holds for Besicovitch almost periodicity. I assume that all my functions are continuous and bounded, which I denote by $C_b$.
For a compact Abelian group $G$, we can define for $t\in G$ an operator $\tau_t:C_b(G)\to C_b(G)$ by
$$ [\tau_t f](g):= f\big( g-t \big) \quad \text{for all} \quad f\in C_b(G) \quad \text{and} \quad g\in G. $$
A Bohr almost-periodic function is a function in the  uniform norm closure of finite linear combinations of characters or trigonometric polynomials.  It is also equivalent to two other conditions.
The set of $\epsilon$ almost periods of $f$ is defined as
$$ \mathfrak{ap}_\epsilon(f):=\{ t\in G: \Vert f- \tau_t(f) \Vert_\infty<\epsilon  \}. $$
$f$ is Bohr-almost periodic if and only if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a compact subset $K\subseteq G$ such that $G = \cup_{t\in \mathfrak{ap_\epsilon}}(t+K)$.
Also, $f$ is Bohr-almost periodic if and only if $\{ \tau_t(f): t\in G \}$ is relatively compact in $\big( C_b(G), \Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty \big)$.
For Besicovitch almost periodicty on amenable groups, one can define the Besicovitch semi-norm for a Van-Hove sequence $\mathcal{A}=\{ A_n \}$ by
$$ \Vert f\Vert_{Bes}= \underset{n\to \infty}{\limsup} \frac{1}{m_G(A_n)} \int_{A_n} \vert f \vert dm_G, $$
where $m_G$ is the Haar measure on $G$. We then say $f\in C_b(G)$ is Besicovitch almost-periodic if it is the Besicovitch seminorm closure of linear combinations of characters. Are there equivalent formulations like in the Bohr almost periodic case? Something like:
The following are equivalent:

$f$ is Besicovitch almost periodic

$\{ \tau_t(f): t\in G \}$ is relatively compact in $\big( C_b(G), \Vert \cdot \Vert_{Bes} \big)$.

For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a compact $K$ such that $G= \cup_{t \in \mathfrak{ap}_\epsilon^{Bes}(f) } \big( t+K \big)$, where


$$ \mathfrak{ap}_\epsilon^{Bes}(f):=\{ t\in G: \Vert f- \tau_t(f) \Vert_{Bes}<\epsilon  \}. $$
I saw the equivalence between the first and second point in the question on this thread in math overflow, but I haven't found this sort of statement elsewhere so I was wondering whether it is true. I'm not well versed with these notions, but I thought this might be well known to people working with Besicovitch almost periodic functions.

This is only a partial answer, but I think the third bullet is not equivalent to Besicovitch almost periodicity. More precisely, relying on definition 2.1 in the paper Pure Point Diffraction and Mean, Besicovitch and Weyl Almost Periodicity, the third bullet is equivalent to mean almost periodicity. Besicovitch mean almost periodicity implies mean almost periodicity but the converse is not true.
I still don't know about whether the first two bullets are indeed equivalent.
